# Redirect an specific URL to another specific URL for same domain

Tags: wordpress

Well I have been using a wordpress site. I want to redirect few urls. for example:

http://example.com/test To http://example.com/final/game

I tried using htaccess but got no success yet.

Comment: share your htaccess code here?

Comment: Redirect 301 /test/ http://example.com/final/game

Comment: Can you please give me a solution how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RedirectMatch 301 /test/ /final/game/

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: it is redirect to some other page?

Answer (score 1):

If that's a wordpress site then you don't have to waste your time in htaccess, you can simply use different redirect plugin to redirect your url. One of most popular plugin is [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Comment: I don't want to use plugin. I want to do it with htaccess

Answer (score 0):

looks like your missing the http:// from your redirect:

Redirect 301 /test/ http://example.com/final/game